# CSS changer in PHP

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Based off of [customizer live preview layout picker](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/230347/customizer-live-preview-layout-picker), hats off to that post. I've been looking for a live layout changer for WordPress for the longest time. This works perfectly, however I'd like to know is there a more convenient way to write the CSS in this PHP function? I looked into possibly loading/unloading style sheets but that requires too many requests. Also I noticed this adds blank, duplicate elements in the dev tools rules.

Here's the code, any help in the right direction is appreciated:

```
$options = get_option( 'layout_selector_option' ); ?>

    <style type="text/css">

        /* Layout #1 */

          .layout { <?php if( $options['site_layout'] == '1' ) { ?> 
            display: flex; <?php } ?> 
          } 
          .posts { <?php if( $options['site_layout'] == '1' ) { ?> 
            order: 1; <?php } ?> 
          } 
          .sidebar { <?php if( $options['site_layout'] == '1' ) { ?> 
            order: 2; <?php } ?> 
          }
          @media (max-width: 800px) {
            .layout { <?php if( $options['site_layout'] == '1' ) { ?> 
              display: flex;
              flex-direction: column; <?php } ?>
            }
          }

    </style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code would be much more compact and readable if you make use of a single PHP `if` conditional for the layout, and wrap **all** of the CSS rules inside of it:

```
<?php $options = get_option('layout_selector_option'); ?>

<style type="text/css">

    /* Layout #1 */

    <?php if ($options['site_layout'] == '1') { ?>

      .layout {
        display: flex;
      } 
      .posts {
        order: 1;
      } 
      .sidebar {
        order: 2;
      }
      @media (max-width: 800px) {
        .layout {
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: column;
        }
      }

    <?php } ?>

</style>
```

Or, alternatively, given this appears to be an entire **layout** that you're changing, you could make use of different stylesheets (such as `layout1.css`), and reference *those* based on the conditional:

```
<head>
<?php
  if ($options['site_layout'] == '1') {
    ?> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="layout1.css"> <?php
  }
?>
</head>
```

Which can even make use of the output of `$options['site_layout']` directly, completely **removing** the need for the conditional:

```
<head>
<?php echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="layout' . $options['site_layout'] . '.css">'; ?>
</head>
```

This can also be written by only outputting the PHP in the `href`:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="layout<?php echo $options['site_layout'];?>.css">
</head>
```

Comment: The first option you have is what I initially thought of going for (wrapping each layout option in their own conditional) but since it discolored some of the css and php in vscode (usually when it discolors, something needs fixing), I didn't want to risk breaking it at first. However, it does actually work, thanks Obsidian! It even got rid of the duplicate elements. I'll tinker around with the rest of your solutions to see which is the better method.